# Question on the application of the property of memorylessness of exponential distribution at example

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

So I recently leant about exponential distribution and there got to know about its memorylessness. Then I attempted a question that went like this -

Q1) A site gets 3 visitors by a click every hour so μ = 20 minutes

a) Find the probability of getting a click in the first minute - ANS 0.05

b) If the site did not get a visit in the first 20 minutes, find the probability of getting a click in the 21st minute. - ANS 0.05

Here the memorylessness property of exponential distribution is applied and we see that both the q have the same probability.

Q2) Then I found another problem where we have to find the probability of a click happening in the 2nd minute the explanation was that the probability of not getting a click in the first minute and getting a click in the second minute this came out to be (.95)*(.05) essentially.

I am having trouble with the 2nd problem, isn't it the same as part b) of the 1st problem and so the probability should be 0.05 instead of the given answer due to the memorylessness of exponential distributions?

Comment: Coin tossed are also a memoryless process. Can you quote the **exact** wording of your question ?

Comment: my problem is the probability of a click happening in the 2nd minute came out to be (.95)*(.05) 

Now I am having a problem understanding it as isn't it the same as part b) of the 1st 
problem - If the site did not get a visit in the first 20 minutes, find the probability of getting a click in the 21st minute... and so the probability should be 0.05 instead of the given answer due to the memorylessness of exponential distributions?

Comment: I have addressed your doubt in the posted question in an answer. For the 21st minute, exactly the same logic will apply to properly framed questions.

Answer (score 1):

Why I asked for the **exact** wording is to clearly get the intention of the questions

- If you ask (regardless of what has happened in the past), what is the probability of a click in the 2nd minute, the answer is $0.05$ due to the memorylessness property.
- If you ask what is the probability that the *first* click occurs in the 2nd minute, the answer is $0.95*0.05$